# get data in current model. yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Can't get data from current model.

```
     class Category extends ActiveRecord
        {
    .......................................
.......
            public function fields() {
              $fields = parent::fields();

              $this->ParentCategory = static::find()->all();

              $fields ['ParentCategory'] = 'ParentCategory';

              return $fields;
```

I need to get all records but I've got "PHP Fatal Error","message":"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".

Comment: "`all()`" means: "please fetch every single record from the table and return it. I don't think that is what you are looking for, but you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: but I need to get every single record form the table. I thing i got either recursion or infinite loop

Comment: Well then the error you mention is just what it says, it probably wasn't able to complete the fetch of that entire table in less than 30 seconds, which is the (default) maximum length a PHP script is allowed to run. You can change this in the php.ini or via `set_time_limit()`. Hard to say more without more information

Comment: but there are only few records in DB - 5 or 8. 
if I'll write this function in other model - it will work without any problems.
but when i try to get records  from current model  I have this problem.

Comment: Since the `fields` function is used to return a list of columns in your model table, I'm thinking it is probably called by an ActiveQuery. So chances are that your `static::find()->all()` comes back into this function, causing an endless loop like you said. Comment out the line and if it works like that then that is the problem.

Comment: thank's a lot. i solve it due to rest action

Answer (score 0):

because your data steel big and  ))
You need to change that in the php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 1000
```